# Evaluating expression tree using std::map

Tags: c++, tree, expression, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I am using abstract data types to evaluate an expression tree as oppposed to a different way previously and i am not sure how to use  the map function exactly.

Okay so this function

```
int arithmetic_expression::evaluate_Expression(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap)
{
if (tree != NULL){
    return(tree->evaluate(ipMap));
}
else
    return(0);
}
```

calls this function, and in this function i am not sure what to return

```
int Tree::evaluate(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap){

//not sure what to put in return to evaluate the expression
if(NodeType==TYPE_OPERATOR)
{
    return())
}
```

I previously did this a different way like this

```
int arithmetic_expression::evaluate_Expression()
{
if (topPtr != NULL)
    return(evaluateTree(topPtr));
else
{
    std::cout<< "Invalid expression: returning 0"<< std::endl;
    return(0);
}
}
}
}


int arithmetic_expression::evaluateTree(TreeNodePtr rootPtr)
{
if ((rootPtr->Op=="+") | (rootPtr->Op=="-")|(rootPtr->Op=="*")|(rootPtr->Op== "/")) 
{
    if (rootPtr->Op=="+")
        {
            return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)+ evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
        }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="-")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)- evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="*")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)* evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="/")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)/ evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
}
else
{
    int Number;
    std::istringstream(rootPtr->Op) >> Number;
    return(Number);
}
```

Comment: `|` is the *bitwise or*. You probably meant `||`.

Comment: based on what i did in a previous program. how do i implement the same thing but using the map thing instead. Do i do if nodetype = + then return evaluate(leftPtr->ipmap) + evaluate(rightPtr->ipmap) ect ect. sort of like the previous one

Answer (score 1):

You do want a tree for the expression evaluation, and `std::map` uses a tree internally. That doesn't mean they're a natural match.

In particular, a `std::map<std::string, int>` can hold only one occurance of each string, and is ordered by those strings. Your expression tree can hold multiple identical subexpressions, and is ordered by the arithmetic rules for expression evaluation.